# C# Binding to an ObservableCollection in another ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have an ObserveableCollection which contains another ObserveableCollection. In my WPF i set a binding to Persons.Lectures.
My problem is now when i change any value in the "lectures" collection, the "persons" collection doesn't notify that und my binding neither. Is this generally a problem when using an ObserveableCollection into another ObserveableCollection ?

How can i solve this, so that my binding will react ?

Answer (score 3):

The ObservableCollection implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), which notifies you of changes (additions, change of order, etc) to the collection itself.

If you want your bindings to update then the actual objects contained in the ObservableCollection must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). You may notice that the collection does implement that interface too, but that is to notify of changes to the properties of the collection object itself, NOT changes to the properties of its contents.

Comment: Here's a nice little slice of Caliburn.Micro which does what you need.  [Caliburn.Micro.INPC](https://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.INPC/1.3.1).  It doesn't require MVVM.  Marshal code to the UI thread, INPC (including manually raising property changed from outside the scope of the class), and BindableCollection<T> which inherits from ObservableCollection<T> and handles property changed and collection changed & adds extra functionality for better control.

Just inherit from this base class and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on your scenario here.  Is "Persons" an ObservableCollection?  Yet, you're saying that it has a "Lectures" property, which isn't the case on a standard ObservableCollection.  Is this a new class inherited from ObservableCollection that has a "Lectures" property that is also an ObservableCollection?

I'm guessing that you've got an ObservableCollection of Person objects, which themselves have an ObservableCollection of Lectures.  Is that the case?  If so, maybe you're just constructing your Binding incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I (and WPF in general) prefer `ObservableCollection`, I would suggest you to use `BindingList` for this "specific" puspose.

As far as I know, `BindingList` in another `BindingList` would propagate the collection changed notifications up the hierarchy without any extra plumbing.

Try and let me know.